# Speech Recoginition giving error swift error domain=nsosstatuserrordomain code=2003334207 "(null)"

Tags: swift3, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to use speech recoginition in view controller
I have write following code for the same but getting error:

```
swift error domain=nsosstatuserrordomain code=2003334207 "(null)"
```

I have also created an audio file in root directory with File.m4a but getting nil error after line number 2 below is the code:

```
case .authorized:
                isButtonEnabled = true
                do{
                    Linenumber = "1"
                let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "m4a")
                Linenumber = "2"

                    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path!)
                    Linenumber = "3"
                    self.audioPlayer = sound
                    Linenumber = "4"
                    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
                    Linenumber = "5"
                    sound.play()
                    let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
                    Linenumber = "6"
                    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(
                        url: path!)
                    Linenumber = "7"
                    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: {
                        (result, error) in
                        Linenumber = "8"
                        self.meetingnotes.text = self.meetingnotes.text + " " + (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)!
                    })
                }
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.
PS. I have already created a entry in Info.plist
Thanks